# Have Laravel/PHP technical limitations over Spring/Java when building, scaling and etc a Rest API?

Tags: java, php, spring, laravel

I am working with a person that says that PHP is a language that should be "forgotten". He says that php is not meant to be used for enterprise projects. Now we should use only Phyton, Ruby, C#, Kotlin (even Java should be avoided if possible). He said that php projects are hard to maintain, test and etc. Does his statements make sense? With this trend microservices, TDD, BDD, Unit Testing, scalability PHP/Laravel limited compared to other technologies, for example Spring/Java? If PHP is limited, what would be the most proeminent faults?

Comment: This question is way too broad and opinionated to answer. Most of the web runs on PHP, its a language specifically used/developed for web applications. Its maintainability depends on the developer that wrote the code.

Comment: A whole book could be written about why PHP is bad.